# Como inserir uma linha em um DataFrame Pandas no meio de outras linhas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou com um output de dados de sensores que tem a seguinte estrutura desejada:

*--- Inicio ---*

$LAGM,Colar03,Amarelo,32262,-31226,-5120,-104,40,190,1662.00,1670.00,236.00,MGAL
$GPGGA,113203.181,2026.6812,S,05443.4264,W,1,03,3.4,0.0,M,4.8,M,,0000*68
$GPGSA,A,2,07,23,30,,,,,,,,,,3.5,3.4,0.9*3E
$GPGSV,3,1,12,30,54,247,37,07,54,185,38,09,51,135,32,28,37,352,10*7E
$GPGSV,3,2,12,23,31,096,43,06,20,297,26,03,18,029,30,08,10,088,33*77
$GPGSV,3,3,12,02,10,263,24,05,05,218,28,16,00,146,,27,00,118,*70
$GPRMC,113203.181,A,2026.6812,S,05443.4264,W,000.0,000.0,241017,,,A*63
$GPVTG,000.0,T,,M,000.0,N,000.0,K,A*0D

--- Fim ---

Onde a informação no DataFrame do Pandas é posicionada de forma sequencial, como uma tabela e seus registros. Acontece que o sensor, em alguns blocos de código, simplesmente não registrou alguns dados, ficando com informações faltantes, conforme o bloco a seguir:

*--- Inicio ---*

$LAGM,Colar03,Amarelo,6,27904,6144,332,-172,-216,1536,109,24,MGAL
$GPGGA,120025,0,N,0,E,0,0,0,0,M,0,MŽÆF¦F&Ö
$GPRMC,120025,V,0,N,0,E,0,0,280606,,,N*78
$GPVTG,0,T,,M,0,N,0,K,N*02

--- Fim ---

É possível notar que falta informação, bem como a existência de caracteres Non-ASCII (Esse é outro tratamento). Minha principal contribuição no mestrado é o pré-processamento, onde consiste em resgatar essas linhas faltantes e colocar uma média entre os valores, resgatando a informação perdida.

Porém, no excel é possível executar isso "no braço" de acordo com o gif animado abaixo:

[image: Inserindo uma linha]

Onde ele arrasta os registros existentes para baixo para podermos acrescentar novos dados nas linhas criadas, porém não consegui encontrar uma forma de adicionar essa informação no Pandas igual a imagem.

Gostaria de saber, é possível executar essa ação de inserir uma linha com nova informação no Pandas com alguma função ou mesmo contornar isso com Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que temos esse DataFrame:

```
d = {'nome': ['maria', 'Pedro', 'Mario'], 'idade': [30, 45, 36], 'estado': ['SP', 'BA', 'RJ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

>>> print df
  estado  idade   nome
0     SP     30  maria
1     BA     45  Pedro
2     RJ     36  Mario
```

Usando essa função que eu copiei daqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe

```
def inserir_linha(idx, df, df_inserir):
    dfA = df.iloc[:idx, ]
    dfB = df.iloc[idx:, ]

    df = dfA.append(df_inserir).append(dfB).reset_index(drop = True)

    return df
```

Essa função quebra o DataFrame em dois (dfA e dfB) em um id predeterminado (idx) e depois junta dfA com o df_inserido com o dfB nessa ordem.

Usando a função:

```
d_iserido = d = {'nome': ['nome_iserido1','nome_2'], 'idade': [0,100], 'estado': ['EXEMPLO', 'olaa']}
df_iserido = pd.DataFrame(data = d_iserido)
df = inserir_linha(1, df, df_iserido)

>>> print df
    estado  idade           nome
0       SP     30          maria
1  EXEMPLO      0  nome_iserido1
2     olaa    100         nome_2
3       BA     45          Pedro
4       RJ     36          Mario
```

Comment: Obrigado AlexCiuffa, isso resolveu o meu problema de forma bem eficiente. Agora só preciso desenvolver uma iteração que percorra todos os dados e que chame essa função. Mais uma vez agradecido!